# on a double integral without substitution.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was asked to solve this double integral without using a variable substitution:

$$  \iint_A e^{-x}e^{-y} \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y  $$

where $A = \left\{\dfrac x {x+y}< z,\, x+y < w,\, x> 0,\, y> 0,\, w>0,\, 0<z<1 \right\}$

Using the substitution $t = x, u = x+y$ I arrived at the solution: $$z(-we^{-w}-e^w+1)$$

Without substitution I notice that $x < \dfrac{zy}{1-z}$ and $x < w-y$ so $y < w(1-z)$ for these $x$.

Also if $y > w(1-z)$ I get that $y$ must be less than $w$  so I have that the integral becomes

$$\int_0 ^{w(1-z)} \int_0^{zy/(1-z)} e^{-x} e^{-y} \,dx\, dy + \int_{w(1-z)}^w \int_0^{w-y} e^{-x} e^{-y} \, dx \, dy $$

Is this correct? I have tried computing it a few times but I don't get the correct answer, also I have found no source on the syntax for double integrals in wolphram alpha (if somebody could tell me I would be happy). **I don't ask for the computations just if the way the integral is setup is correct**.

Comment: I'd take $x$ outermost. Then you get the range $(z^{-1}-1)x < y < w-x$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks, but would my setup be correct even if harder?

Comment: In principle it is correct of course, and I didn't find any calculation errors, so it should be correct also in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is correct. It is rather easy to make a sign error in the calculations, and I expect that is what happened when you didn't get the correct result.

We get a simpler expression if we take $x$ outermost, since then we don't need to split the outer integral. The condition $\frac{x}{x+y} < z$ can be rewritten as $(z^{-1}-1)x < y$, and so for the integral with respect to $y$ we have the limits $(z^{-1} - 1)x < y < w-x$, which only is a nonempty range for $x < zw$. Thus the integral becomes

\begin{align}
\int_0^{zw} e^{-x} \int_{(z^{-1}-1)x}^{w-x} e^{-y}\,dy\,dx
&= \int_0^{zw} e^{-x}\bigl(e^{(1-z^{-1})x} - e^{x-w}\bigr)\,dx \\
&= \int_0^{zw} e^{-x/z} - e^{-w}\,dx \\
&= \bigl(-ze^{-x/z}\bigr)\biggr\rvert_0^{zw} - (zw-0)e^{-w} \\
&= z - ze^{-w} - zw e^{-w} \\
&= z(1 - e^{-w} - we^{-w}).
\end{align}